Installing ubuntu on a Dell laptop (Windows 10, i5 8th generation)
I have Windows 10 installed on my Laptop (G3, Core i5, 8th generation). I downloaded the Ubuntu 24.04 from the website and made the bootable USB using Rufus.
It shows the following remove the installation medium message after the installation finishes.
And this message too.

But after a while Windows starts again and I do not find any Ubuntu, so how to install it successfully?

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.24

Open UEFI settings, and choose hte default bootloader to be Ubuntu
